# php mysql nested query fails with order of the mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql, nested

This is really bugging me.  We have new servers running php 5 and mysql 5.  Some mysql queries that have always worked before have strange errors now.  There seems to be some craziness in the order of the mysql connection initializations.  Here is what I mean:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_time_limit(0);

$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "someguy", "someguy");
mysql_select_db("db1", $db);

$db2 = mysql_connect("localhost", "someguy", "someguy");
mysql_select_db("db2", $db2);

$sql = "select * from app_1_51 ".
       "where submitted = 'Y' ".
       "and approved = 'N' ";
$res2 = mysql_query($sql, $db2);
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2))
{

  echo $row2['appid'].": ".$row2['fname']." ".$row2['lname']."\n";

  $sql = "select count(*) as reccnt from applications where hohssn = '".$row2['ssn']."' and appstatus in ('','P','I','H','R') ";
  $res = mysql_query($sql, $db);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
  echo "           ".$row2['ssn'].": ".$row['reccnt']."\n";

}
?>
```

This code above makes all of the resource ($res variable) inside the while loop false.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_time_limit(0);

$db2 = mysql_connect("localhost", "someguy", "someguy");
mysql_select_db("db2", $db2);

$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "someguy", "someguy");
mysql_select_db("db1", $db);

$sql = "select * from app_1_51 ".
       "where submitted = 'Y' ".
       "and approved = 'N' ";
$res2 = mysql_query($sql, $db2);
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2))
{

  echo $row2['appid'].": ".$row2['fname']." ".$row2['lname']."\n";

  $sql = "select count(*) as reccnt from applications where hohssn = '".$row2['ssn']."' and appstatus in ('','P','I','H','R') ";
  $res = mysql_query($sql, $db);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
  echo "           ".$row2['ssn'].": ".$row['reccnt']."\n";

}
?>
```

this code above makes the resource variable ($res2) for the while loop query false.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_time_limit(0);

$db2 = mysql_connect("localhost", "someguy", "someguy");
mysql_select_db("db2", $db2);

$sql = "select * from app_1_51 ".
       "where submitted = 'Y' ".
       "and approved = 'N' ";
$res2 = mysql_query($sql, $db2);
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2))
{

  echo $row2['appid'].": ".$row2['fname']." ".$row2['lname']."\n";

  $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "someguy", "someguy");
  mysql_select_db("db1", $db);

  $sql = "select count(*) as reccnt from applications where hohssn = '".$row2['ssn']."' and appstatus in ('','P','I','H','R') ";
  $res = mysql_query($sql, $db);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
  echo "           ".$row2['ssn'].": ".$row['reccnt']."\n";

}
?>
```

And this code runs fine until I use the $res to make an insert.  Then the insert will work but nothing afterwards.  Has anyone run into this before?  I have used this methodology for years without any issues.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: try get error using `mysql_error()` after query execution to get error message

Comment: And of course, don't use mysql_* function, they are deprecated USE `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead

Comment: Can you report the errors you get? Always print errors when debugging. I usually print both error and the query that generated it

Comment: The only error I get is a warning, "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource".  That is because the resource is false.  mysql_error() does not return any errors.

Comment: oh, and Yuri, I do the same, but I was trying to cut down the code to only the issue.  Why would the order of the connection init cause problems in different named DB connections and resources.  Very strange to me.

Comment: Why not just use 1 database connection and mysql_select_db to change the db you need before your next query?

Comment: Wouldnt that interfere with the result of the initial query that is running while in the while loop.  In other words, I thought you couldnt change the resource or db while mid loop.  Thats why the 2nd db.

Comment: I found what my issue was it the third example.  When doing a select after the insert to find the newly created record id, I didnt set the mysql_query to a resource.  This is why the rest of my script failed there, but it still doesnt explain the strange behavior of example 1 and 2.  I am converting this code to mysqli now though, and so far it doesnt have the same issue.  Its probably a bug in php mysql 5.  I hate change!  I need to change my ID here to Dan [depricated], so ppl know not to tell me to upgrade :)